# Why can't I save my Xbox 360 game in XNA?

Tags: xml, xna, stream, loading, save

I'm having problems with saving my game and I've spent hours searching for solutions without any luck. I used this code that was written in someone's blog:

```
public class SaveandLoad
{
    StorageDevice device;
    string containerName = "ChainedWingsContainer";
    string filename = "mysave.sav";
    public struct SaveGame
    {
        public int s_mission;
    }

    public void InitiateSave()
    {
        if (!Guide.IsVisible)
        {
            device = null;
            StorageDevice.BeginShowSelector(PlayerIndex.One, this.SaveToDevice, null);
        }
    }

    void SaveToDevice(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        device = StorageDevice.EndShowSelector(result);
        if (device != null && device.IsConnected)
        {
            SaveGame SaveData = new SaveGame()
            {
                s_mission = Game1.mission,
            };
            IAsyncResult r = device.BeginOpenContainer(containerName, null, null);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(r);
            if (container.FileExists(filename))
                 container.DeleteFile(filename);
            Stream stream = container.CreateFile(filename);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGame));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, SaveData);
            stream.Close();
            container.Dispose();
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
        }
    }

    public void InitiateLoad()
    {
        if (!Guide.IsVisible)
        {
            device = null;
            StorageDevice.BeginShowSelector(PlayerIndex.One, this.LoadFromDevice, null);
        }
    }

    void LoadFromDevice(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        device = StorageDevice.EndShowSelector(result);
        IAsyncResult r = device.BeginOpenContainer(containerName, null, null);
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(r);
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
        if (container.FileExists(filename))
        {
            Stream stream = container.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGame));
            SaveGame SaveData = (SaveGame)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            container.Dispose();
            //Update the game based on the save game file
            Game1.mission = SaveData.s_mission;
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I run it, I get this message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage.dll

Additional information: A new container cannot be opened until all previouses containers used by this PlayerIndex have been disposed.

I've looked around for answers and most of the suggestions suggest to use the Using statement. So I used Using like so:

```
    void SaveToDevice(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        device = StorageDevice.EndShowSelector(result);
        if (device != null && device.IsConnected)
        {
            SaveGame SaveData = new SaveGame()
            {
                s_mission = Game1.mission,
            };
            IAsyncResult r = device.BeginOpenContainer(containerName, null, null);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            using (StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(r))
            {
                if (container.FileExists(filename))
                    container.DeleteFile(filename);
                Stream stream = container.CreateFile(filename);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGame));
                serializer.Serialize(stream, SaveData);
                stream.Close();
                container.Dispose();
            }
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
        }
    }
```

But I still get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The person in this [post](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/41010/240452.aspx) was having the same problem, caused by some kind of exception handling outside of the scope of the using statement which is causing dispose not to be correctly called. Try wrapping your using statement in a try catch instead.

Also, I found this [post](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/17996/93894.aspx) to be helpful while searching for a solution.

Good luck.

Comment: Fantastic! I tried the Try and Catch and it worked. Now I can save and load perfectly. However what do I put in the catch block? I don't understand what that is for. I know it's for exceptions but what kind?

Comment: Nevermind. I found a use for it. Thanks a million once a gain.